# Elementary Reduction Matrices as Linear Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I like to think about matrices as linear maps (for obvious reasons). Now I understand that elementary reduction matrices are motivated by Gauß-Jordan Elimination.

Can you see any plausible way to think of elementary reduction matrices as linear maps?

Comment: Maybe this will be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix

Comment: Multiplying by a scalar is like scaling in a direction, switching rows is like a reflection, and the affine row addition is like a shear transformation.